# CSS html tables left and right border

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to write some CSS that will make it so my html table only has borders horizontally, and no borders vertically in between columns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

<style type="text/css">

box-table-a{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    /*border-width: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#box-table-a th{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe;
    border-right:1px solid #b9c9fe;
    border-left:1px solid #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
}
#box-table-a td{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#box-table-a tr:hover td{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
}
</style>
```

This results in a table with white borders on all sides.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

*EDIT*
I can get it to do what I want here: http://jsfiddle.net/QZwt5/26/
but when I take this exact table, and exact css into dreamweaver and then ftp to my server I am still getting thin white lines in-between each cell.
[image http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/9135/temppb.jpg](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/9135/temppb.jpg)

Also just noticed that if I turn off normalized in fiddle that the borders appear on the table there.

Everything is running on an Ubuntu server, I'm building it in winXP and then ftp to Apache, so there might be some permission problems interfering with the CSS?

Comment: may be this is causing the border top and bottom as well. `border-right:1px solid #b9c9fe;
    border-left:1px solid #b9c9fe;`

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved simply using CSS

HTML

```
<table border="1" id="table">
<tr>
<td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Row 3, cell 1</td>
<td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

CSS

```
tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QZwt5/)

Comment: I can get it to do what I want with jsFiddle, but when I copy and paste the working CSS from there to my server it still has white borders around every cell.  I also deleted the rest of my style sheet to see if I could just get these styles working, and to make sure there was no interference.  Still with no change

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but from just looking at your code, you never "remove" the borders on the left and right.  Try adding

```
#box-table-a td{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, tried adding those but to no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the left and right borders from the `th` cells, and see if that fixes the problem.

If it does, set the `border-left` and `border-right` on the `td` cells to be the same colour as the background, to "hide" them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough

```
table tr { border: 1px #000 solid; }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/QZwt5/1/)